# Update PKIClient on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: powershell, ssl, windows-server-2008-r2

I need to create a self-signed certificate for SSL connections to an IIS-App on a Windows Server 2012 R2 with Powershell 5.1 installed.

On Windows 10 I use successfully:

```
$subject = "something"
$ip = "<my ip>"

New-SelfSignedCertificate -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(15) -CertstoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -Subject $subject -TextExtension @("2.5.29.17={text}DNS=$env:COMPUTERNAME&IPAddress=${ip}")
```

But on MS Server 2012 R2 the parameters `subject`, `notafter` and `TextExtention` are not supported.

I can't seem to use MakeCert.exe instead, as I am not able to set 'subject alternative name' (the field that is set by the parameter `TextExtension`) and that seems to be required when I connect with a browser.

```
makecert /n "CN=MyCert" /sr localmachine /ss my /l 2048 /eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 /m 300 /r
```

I read that I could update PKIClient for a newer version of the New-SelfsignedCertificate command. So I tried:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
Update-Module PKIClient
```

The last command doesn't work. The error message says that PKIClient wasn't updated, because no such modul was found in the module path.

The PSModulePath contains:
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;
C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\

`Install-Module PKIClient` doesn't work either. The error message says that PKIClient couldn't be found and that I should check Get-PSRepository to list all sources.

```
Get-PSRepository

Name                      InstallationPolicy   SourceLocation
----                      ------------------   --------------    
PSGallery                 Untrusted            https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2
```

So how do I get the current PKIClient on this machine? Or how can I use MakeCert to fill the required field?

Comment: It appears the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35924054/new-selfsignedcertificate-on-win2012-r2-has-less-parameters and on that post referenced there if that alone does not suffice to get you what you need.